# Is it possible to make the background of the chat transparent?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to make the background transparent without any mods? You can do this via chat settings but you the text will also be more transparent. So is there a way to this via texture pack or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't aware that you could achieve this by using a texture pack, however, you can use a mod called TabbyChat to make your chat background transparent (I'm pretty sure). I've used TabbyChat with the Cosmic Client, and it provided a transparency option. I hope this helps!
https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/tabbychat-2